# Split the_content() into 2 divs for first x letters

Tags: php, wordpress

On single.php this is used to display post content:

```
<div class="post-content">
    <?php the_content(); ?>
</div>
```

How could i break the content(without using more tag in WP editor) so it looks like this:

```
<div class="post-content">
    first 100 letters of the post
</div>
<div class="post-content">
    remaining part of the post
</div>
```

I need to do this because i will add a slider in between those 2 parts.

Comment: are you using gutenberg or not?

Comment: can you use <!--more--> tag?

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna to split content by word count use `wp_trim_words` function.
here is an example of code that you can use it (I didn't check it).

```
<?php $content = get_the_content();?>
$first_slice = wp_trim_words($content,100);
$second_slice = substr($content,strlen($first_slice),strlen($content));
echo '<div class="post-content">'.wpautop($first_slice).'</div>';
echo '<div class="post-content">'.wpautop($second_slice).'</div>';
```

Comment: this also works great but the problem is that the <p> tags are removed from the post so there isnt any spacing

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $content = get_the_content(); ?>
<div class="post-content">
    <?php echo substr($content, 0, 100); ?>
</div>
<div class="post-content">
    <?php echo substr($content, 101, strlen($content)); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: this works great with 100 characters, any way to limit it to 100 words?

Comment: Yes this is a function to limit 100 words wp_trim_words($content, 100, '')

Comment: this works great, thanks, but for some reason paragraph tags are removed... any workaround with that?

Comment: you can try apply_filters('the_content', wp_trim_words($content, 100, '')) function and it will work

Comment: that works great in second block, but in first block all text is wrapped in 1 paragraph (in admin panel there are more paragraphs).... i know i ask a lot, but if you can help, great, if not, i will mark the reply as helpful

Comment: html_entity_decode( wp_trim_words( htmlentities( $content ),100, '' ) )